# How to get webLinks having specific attribute in HTTPUnit

Tags: java, http-unit

We have the API for getting all the WebLinks known as response.getLinks() assuming you have fetched the WebResponse in response. See the problem is I want to fetch only those anchor tags which have specific attribute like all those anchor tags which have data-class attribute and value is true.

```
<a href="#" data-class="true"></a> //Qualify
<a href="#">?</a> // Does not qualify
```

It is possible to get all the links and traverse them and identify the anchors of interest. But I dont want to do this long procedure.

Does any short method exist to get weblinks having specific property in HTTPUnit?

Comment: You might want to file a feature request at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=6550&atid=356550